# Google Pay Push provisioning activity result with activity result launcher api

Tags: android, google-pay, activity-result-api

I'm trying to implement Google Pay push provisioning, and get a result from the activity provided by google where users go by the standard flow of adding a payment method in Google wallet. So the problem is that the `com.google.android.gms.tapandpay.TapAndPayClient#pushTokenize()` function requires a request code which you should handle in `onActivityResult` as shown [image: here] but `onActivityResult` is depricated.
Is there any way to integrate the new activity result launcher in this case, so I could pass a request code and handle it with activity result launcher?

I tried to look around in official docs of activity result api, but couldn't find how it's possible to replace onActivityResult in scenarios like this